How to Use Rotation of an IK-Controlled Bone as a Variable?
I have set up an arm for a character with two bones and an IK handle, and I want the rotation of the forearm bone to control the value of a shape key I set up. the shape key is there to correct some deformities that occur, when bending the arm.
My issue is that, because the forearm bone's rotation is controlled by an IK handle, its rotation in the transform channel does not change.
Is there a way to use the rotation of the forearm bone to control the value of the shape key?

You can use the "Rotational Difference" function for Driver's variable, evaluating the angle between two bones of the IK chain.
If the rest pose has an angle, that will create a rest pose value, which will have to be subtracted from results in the driver's expression.


In your example image, you have a rectangular arm, that is actually what I have as well. Do you know how to make it so the arm stays the same thickness, making it look more natural?

There are 3 main tecniques: 1) ensuring that every half of the limb is totally weighted to one bone only, so to avoid any deformation in theese trait, leaving all stretching in a little area. 2) Adding extra loops and geometry to better absorb the deformation. 3) Using the "Mantain volume" option in the Armature modifier. Beside theese, we go for corrective shape keys and corrective bones.

I have made each half of the arm totally waited to one bone. I don't think option 3 will work (I've tried). do you know of a driver setup that would keep the thickness of the arm the same?

Maybe ask a new question showing the actual deform and the desired end shape.

That is a good suggestion, I will do that
